# Is it possible to round in Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to round in Jade.

I have a variable that looks like this: **9.039444444444445**.

Is it possible to output this number as: **9**?

Thanks in advance for all those who support me.

Comment: Ehm, Jade is a template engine.  Isn't Javascript the go-to tool here?  Look here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/#code

Comment: Yep, i know. But its also possible to calculate with Jade. So I thought that also goes round.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jade lets you run unbuffered JavaScript code in the templating engine. Assuming your variable is named `number`

```
- number = Math.round(number)
```

would round `number` to the nearest integer as noted in the [source](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#code) at Robert Harvey's comment, the syntax is standard JavaScript as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Answer (score 7):

`.toFixed()` may also be useful for showing 'clean' numbers: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: Actually, it's `toFixed()`.